# Retrieve html tags as page from database

Tags: java, html

In my header of my site, there is a `textarea` with show more /less option, the content is stored in database as `html tags`. I want to retrieve the content as page. in `textarea`, i will display only first `40 chars`. so when i retrieve `html` tags and remove tags, it will be problem. because i will some style inside content like bold text
ex:

```
<html>
</body>
  <b>this is sample text</b><a href="www.google.com">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

expected result: this is sample text click here

Comment: Check the DB data type. Is it only storing the first 40 chars, like VARCHAR2(40)?

Comment: Why do you want to display html tags in a textarea?

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: I have html content with css style in db,want to display that content in my header part. how can we do it?

Comment: are you using just basic jsp/servlets or any framework like struts2 or are you using or familiar with jstl tags ?

Comment: yes. I'm using basic jsp and servlets as well as struts1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the entire HTML (unless you really have to), I'd say parse the HTML first using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) and store the contents of the `<b>` tags.  If you really need to store the HTML then do that (as @ppeterka mentioned though, check it's not a 40 char max on the db) and parse the result using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) before you populate the textarea.

Comment: The things is, i'm getting the html content from some other person. So I cant do it anything. i want to retrieve those content and display it in header part with what they specified style in that html. NOTE: i'm going to display only 3 lines of that content, after that when i click show more button, it will display entire content with style.

Comment: Yeah but if you're getting the html from some third party, you can still parse it server side using JSoup.  Just do a CURL request with it, it's kind of irrelevant then where the data comes from.  When you say you want to display it in the header - are you using Spring or something as the controller?

Comment: That's easy then, do a GET/POST (whichever to get the content from the RESTful endpoint), parse it, store it, present it to the user, I feel I'm missing something?

Comment: yep. Still i didnt get it.